# Babel don't transpiling code in local package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, yarnpkg

My folders structure looks like this:

```
/testproject
    /local-package
      package.json
    /src
package.json
```

**/testproject/package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "local-package": "file:./local-package",
```

**/testproject/webpack.config.js**

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules(?!\/local-package)/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
```

When I am run `webpack --mode production` I get an error

```
ERROR in ./local-package/components/NotFound.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/pavel/Projects/JS/testproject/local-package/components/NotFound.jsx: Unexpected token (4:2)

  2 |
  3 | const NotFound = () => (
> 4 |   <div>
    |   ^
  5 |     <h3>404 page not found</h3>
  6 |     <p>We are sorry but the page you are looking for does not exist.</p>
  7 |   </div>
```

https://gist.github.com/perevezencev/2c985c5a4f2c2ab9a89b9afd2989d409
Steps to reproduce:

1. clone repo `git clone https://github.com/perevezencev/webpack-error.git`
2. run `yarn link` inside `/webpack-error/local-package`
3. run `yarn link "local-package"` inside `/webpack-error`
4. run `yarn` inside `/webpack-error`
5. run `yarn build` inside `/webpack-error`

Answer (score -2):

Okay I guess you could try this tutorial with working on the latest babel, webpack, and react. It has good examples already, instead of my recreating your project files, just refactor yours like the tutorial.

[react-webpack-babel proj](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-webpack-babel/)

You can also configure react-hot-loader so you can edit your component in real-time when you run a dev server. You add it to .babelrc file.

[react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader)

Comment: I use React and @babel/preset-react